# Windows Scheduled Task - 'Ping' webpage every xx minutes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

What's the best way to have a Windows Server request some webpage every xx minutes?  Coming from the Linux world, I know I can do this with a cron job using curl or wget.  I don't need to save the resulting page, I just need the script to run server-side, as if somebody manually visited the page.  Do I need to install wget for Windows or can I use some existing Windows tool to accomplish this via Scheduled Task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get [**wget for Windows**](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and use a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create simple batch file with somethink like this inside and schedule it via Task Scheduler :) I've test this script on workstation and server - works on both for me.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://serverfault.com/questions/117893/windows-scheduled-task-ping-webpage-every-xx-minutes
```

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try.  My biggest concern is that I don't want 1000 instances of IE running.  I'm hoping that each execution will use the same instance (or close itself after the page has loaded).

Worst case I'll probably build a simple console app to do this for me.